# MySQL query never finishes when doing an ORDER BY and doing a COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate the rank of characters in my table. For whatever reason, the query runs forever whenever I run it with an order by clause.

I have a very similar query running in a different server with a different schema but it's essentially doing the same thing and that does finish almost instantly. I am completely lost as to why this query never finishes and takes forever.

I am indexing almost everything in the characters table and still no luck.

```
KEY `accountid` (`accountid`),
KEY `party` (`party`),
KEY `ranking1` (`level`,`exp`),
KEY `ranking2` (`gm`,`job`),
KEY `idx_characters_gm` (`gm`),
KEY `idx_characters_fame` (`fame`),
KEY `idx_characters_job` (`job`),
KEY `idx_characters_level` (`level`),
KEY `idx_characters_exp` (`exp`),
```

When I don't include the ORDER BY it runs just fine and finishes instantly. When I do, it runs forever.

There are only 28,000 characters in the DB so it can't be that intensive to compute a rank, especially when the limit's only 1.

```
SELECT c.name
    , 1+(
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM msd.characters as rankc
      WHERE rankc.level > c.level 
      LIMIT 1
    ) as jobRank
FROM characters as c
JOIN accounts as a
ON c.accountid = a.id
WHERE c.gm = 0 AND a.banned = 0
ORDER BY c.`level` DESC, c.exp DESC
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 0;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Essentially, each character has a unique job and I want to get the job ranking of that character. The default order of the rankings is by level. That's why I'm doing a comparison in my jobRank SELECT.

Here is an example of my desired result: [desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp5Yi.png)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  There might be better ways to do what you want.

Comment: Doing index not solving the problem, Wrong addressing index can make the problem too. Only create indexes on columns that will be frequently searched against.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok updated. Let me know if you need more sample data or if you get an idea from the desired result.

Comment: @dwir182 Yes I figured but the query never finishes (even with something as simple as this).

Comment: Do you run the query from tool like mysql workbench? as i remember mysql workbench have some bug

Comment: @dwir182 I'm using TablePlus. I don't think the issue is with the application I'm using as I can run a very similar query and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do when having query performance problems is run an explain on your query (just prefix your select statement with 'explain' and you can see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html for more details.)  While you might think you have all the appropriate indexes in place, sometimes the decisions the DBMS engine makes will not be obvious.  Don't be surprised to find one or more full table scans where you thought indexes would be used (that's probably the most common source of 'query never finishes' issues)

Update: based on your explain output, the query is performing multiple full table scans in the subquery which is probably your performance problem.  You want to try to get that subquery using an index so I'd suggest eliminating LIMIT 1 from the subquery (the where clause is filtering out levels you don't want and there's no group by clause so there should only be 1 row returned) and see if that does the job.